# How to process every other line in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print odd lines (1,3,5,7..) without any change, but even lines (2,4,6,8) process with pipeline beginning with grep. I would like to write everything to new file (odd lines without any change and new values for even lines).

I know how to print every other line in awk:

```
awk ' NR % 2 == 1 { print; } NR % 2 ==0 {print; }' file.fasta
```

However, for even lines, I dont want to use `{print; }` but I want to use my grep pipeline instead.

An advice will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `==1{print;}` is redundant, simply `awk 'NR%2' will print odd lines`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're planning to do a simple `grep`, you can do away with the additional step and do the filtering within awk itself, e.g.:

```
awk 'NR % 2 {print} !(NR % 2) && /pattern/ {print}' file.fasta
```

However, if you intend to do a lot more then, as [chepner already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560544/how-to-process-every-other-line-in-bash/11560638#11560638), you can indeed pipe from inside awk. For example:

```
awk 'NR % 2 {print} !(NR % 2) {print | "grep pattern | rev" }' file.fasta
```

That opens a pipe to the command `"grep pattern | rev"` (note the surrounding quotes) and redirects the print output to it. Do note that the output in this case  may not be as you might expect; you will end up with all odd lines being output first followed by the output of the piped command (which consumes the even lines).

---

(In response to your comments) to count the number of chars in each even line, try:

```
awk 'NR % 2 {print} !(NR % 2) {print length($0)}' file.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks. I am about to count number of letters in even lines.

Comment: @Perlnika you can get the number of chars using the `length` command in awk. See updated answer.

Comment: @Perlnika, some fasta files may contain odd chars like `-` or `X`, but you have probably answered what the OP wants.

Comment: @ShawnChin thanks a lot, I used $0 instead of 0 and it works!

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. Should be `length($0)`. Answer updated

Comment: Aha. You spotted it before me ;) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 9):

You can pipe directly from inside `awk`:

```
awk ' NR % 2 == 1 { print; } NR % 2 ==0 {print | "grep -o [actgnACTGN] | wc -l"; }' file.fasta
```

Be aware, however, that this will not preserve the order of your input file.

(The selected answer is better for the task at hand, but I'll leave this answer here as an example of piping the print statement to an external command.)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this with awk ' NR % 2 == 1 { print; } NR % 2 ==0 {print | grep -o [actgnACTGN] | wc -l }' file.fasta (in order to count number of letters in line) but there was problem with wc stating: awk: line 1: syntax error at or near wc (so that I guess problem is in my pipeline:)

Comment: What do you mean by not preserving order?

Comment: @Perlnika He means that you will end up with all odd lines being output first followed by the output of the pipe (which consumes all the even lines)

Comment: In the short test I ran, all the odd lines were printed, followed by the even lines that were output by the `grep`. This is because the output of the grep may need to be merged with the output of the `awk`, which may be nondeterminisitic. Also, this is probably inefficient, as I think a separate `grep` is forked for each even line.

Comment: Sorry, there is an error in the quoting that I thought I fixed. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your pipeline output appear in order with your AWK output, you need to close the pipeline at each iteration. This is, of course, very inefficient.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ cmd = "grep -io \047[actgn]\047 | wc -l" } NR % 2 { print } NR % 2 == 0 { print | cmd; close(cmd) }' file.fasta
```

You apparently don't want to count characters that are not in the specified list, so `length($0)` won't work. This will work and should be a lot faster than the pipeline method:

```
awk 'NR % 2 { print } NR % 2 == 0 {n = split($0, a, /[^actgnACTGN]/); print length($0) - n + 1}' file.fasta
```

It works by splitting the line using the characters you *don't* want as delimiters and subtracting the count of the substrings from the length of the line and adding 1. In essence, it subtracts the number of unwanted characters from the length of the line leaving the number of wanted characters as the result.